# One-to-One Relationship between tables that can't share primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

Scenario: Each "User" has 0 or 1 "BankAccount". Each "Company" has 0 or 1 "BankAccount".  "BankAccount" records can not be shared.  How do I setup my database to model this?  I tried this:

> "CompanyBankAccount" table with "BankAccountId" (primary key) as a foreign key from the "BankAccount" table and column "CompanyId" as foreign key from the "Company" Table.
>   "Company" table with a nullable "BankAccountId" column as a foreign key from the "CompanyBankAccount" table.  I followed this same pattern for the user tables.

While this works (enforces the rule that no Company or User can have more than 1 bank account and that no bank account can be shared by another user or company), the creation of a new company or user with a bank account is cumbersome (I must first insert the company/user with a NULL BankAccountId, then insert the new BankAccount record, then insert the new [Company/User]BankAccountRecord, then update the "BankAccountId" field on the company/user record I just inserted).  It seems like there should be an easier way.  Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to omit the BankAccountId column in the Company and User tables-- just index the join table by CompanyId or UserId and you can pull up the BankAccountId easily when you need it.

Comment: The dilemma I'm having (which is not directly related to this question) is that this kind of mapping will still cause my ORM tool to see the relationship between bank account and owner (company or user) as a 0..1:N rather than a 0..1:1 even though the index (UK constraint) will keep that from happening in the database.  Actually, my initial approach has similar drawbacks.  However, my question was about the DB and not about my ORM, and as such; you've answered the question and provided a more elegant solution.  Thank you!  ... now to force my ORM to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a relation table unless you have a many-to-many relation, and you don't need both the relation table and a direct relation between the tables.

There are several ways you can do this, for example with just a `UserId` and `CompanyId` in the `BankAccount` table:

```
User
  UserId int primary key
  ...

Company
  CompanyId int primary key
  ...

BankAccount
  UserId int null
  CompanyId int null
  ...
```

You can put the `BankAccountId` in the `User` and `Company` tables:

```
User
  BankAccountId int null
  ...

Company
  BankAccountId int null
  ...

BankAccount
  BAnkAccountId int primary key
  ...
```

You can use a single key in the `BankAccount` table, and a flag for the type of relation:

```
User
  UserId int primary key
  ...

Company
  CompanyId int primary key
  ...

BankAccount
  OwnerId int not null
  IsCompanyAccount bit not null
  ...
```

Comment: In the scenario you described, there is nothing constraining that the OwnerId on the BankAccount table must be either a CompanyId or a UserId.  I understand that I could enforce this at an application layer, but if possible, I'd like the data integrity to be enforced at the database layer too.

Comment: @KevinBirdwell: I didn't describe a single scenario. They are three separate scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I got moving too fast.  The first scenario you described doesn't enforce that a Bank Account can only belong to a Company or a User but not both.  The second scenario does not enforce that a bank account belongs to just a single user or a single company.  The third scenario, as mentioned above, does not enforce that the owner of the bank account is a valid user or company record.

Comment: @KevinBirdwell: Yes, that is right, you can't have everything... Either scenario is still better than what you started with, where you could have any number of accounts for each company in the CompanyBankAccount table, and yet a different account according to the Company table...

Comment: Agreed, those are better scenarios than the original.  I was hoping someone could suggest an approach that would let the database enforce all the integrity without resorting to convoluted scenarios like my original attempt (that still didn't completely enforce integrity).  I appreciate your suggested scenarios. I'll just have to weigh which one, including antlersoft's, that gives me the best balance of database enforced integrity and usability at the application layer.